# Save plugin loaded with Ajax to cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, caching

So I'm using this code to change the content of my website and loading specific plugins for each "page":

```
$.ajax({
  url: urlPath, 
  type: 'GET',
  success: loadContent //content and plugins are loaded through this
});
```

Now I noticed it doesn't cache the *loaded plugins* from `loadContent`, each time downloading them again and again, thefore the page using *ajax requests* is **0.5s to 1.5s slower** than *simple http requests (obviously after the plugins have already been cached from first load)*.
Using `cache: true/false` doesn't make any difference.

I've read this can't be done, because javascript can't write to disk, but still maybe I missed something and there is a way to cache the plugins and avoid losing additional time on each load?

Comment: You should wait a little longer until you delete a question. I was trying to answer your latest question and was about to finish my answer until I noticed you'd already deleted your question. Yes, [SO does have a major problem with people being plain rude & unhelpful](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d), but know that not *everyone* is like that ;-)

Comment: @JohnSlegers yes I got kind of angry that I didn't ask for any code, just a text answer and people are acting like I've asked for the complete guide to such buttons to be made. Thanks for your reply, it made me feel better. I hope you have a nice day as well :) 
(I know, thanks replies and all this stuff isn't welcomed on SO as well, but whatever)

Comment: Most of the questions I personally find interesting end up getting closed here on SO for stupid reasons like being "too broad" or not containing any code. And I totally agree that it makes no sense whatsoever for people to demand you show some code when you're just trying to figure out if a certain approach makes sense. I guess I relate to your situation because I've stood in your shoes more than once myself ;-)

Comment: With respect to the question you deleted... I'd not go for a full CSS solution. It's quite complicated and not worth the effort. Instead, I'd go for a [sprite](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) where each element (the book, the pencil, ...) is a separate "image" and use those different "images" as backgrounds for div elements. Also, I'd go for svg instead of png if possible. svg support in browsers is quite decent these days and you'd get a more crisp/clean result with a smaller filesize.

Comment: I was about to go the same way, though I didn't know .svg is better, will use it.
You've just motivated me to get back to SO, I just remembered I said I'm not stepping here anymore after a similar situation a few months ago.
Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alternative to cache which is localStorage. Each website has the right to store up to 5 MB of data on the user disk.

So use this to save data:

```
//browser support localStorage
if((typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
    localStorage.setItem("mydataname", data);
}
```

And to retrieve or download a new one:

```
//browser support localStorage
if((typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
    var data = localStorage.getItem("mydataname");
    if(data){ //data does exist in localStorage
        // Use data, no need to download a new version.
    }
    else{ // data doesn't exist, not saved yet or have been removed
        // download new version of data and save it using the above code.
    }
}
else{
    // browser doesn't support localStorage redownload data.
}
```

More about localStorage [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).